# "Physical, speech, and occupational therapy" VS "Physical, speech and occupational therapies"?

Tags: plural-forms

Instinctively I believe "therapies" makes sense because the sentence is referring to 3 'types' of therapy, but it just rolls off the tongue funny.

Anyone have a grammatical reason for which is correct?

Thanks!

P.S regarding tagging I wasn't too sure, I never properly learned grammatical rules growing up and just learned English by figuring out what sounded right/wrong.

Comment: They are both correct. It depends on what you are trying to say. Are you talking about an uncountable generalized concept, or about specific countable instances? You need to provide a context.